# Are static constinit member variables identical to non-type template parameters?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I have a class template for an N-dimensional array:

```cpp
template<typename T, std::size_t... Shape>
class ndarray { ... };
```

One consequence of this template design is that there is an additional 'implicit' template parameter if you will: `std::size_t Size`, the product of all arguments in `Shape`. I have been using a C++17 fold expression (`(1 * ... * Shape)`) where I would typically use `Size` if it weren't dependent on `Shape`, but I'm wondering if adding the following 'alias' would result in any subtle differences in the compiled assembly:

```cpp
template<typename T, std::size_t... Shape>
class ndarray {
    static constinit std::size_t Size = (1 * ... * Shape);
    ...
};
```

Interestingly, the ISO C++20 standard doesn't state whether or not `constinit` implies `inline` as it does for `constexpr` and `consteval`. I think the semantics of `constinit` (especially in relation to `constexpr` variables) only really makes sense if the variable were also `inline`, but its omission from the standard makes me wary of this conclusion.

Comment: Why would you make it a `constinit` variable instead of `constexpr`? Do you plan to modify it later?

Comment: @NicolBolas Wow! Your comment made me look at `constinit` again, and I had completely misunderstood it at first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`constinit` has exactly and *only* one semantic: the expression used to initialize the variable must be a constant expression.

That's it. That's all it does: it causes a compile error if the initializing expression isn't a valid constant expression. In *every other way*, such a variable is identical to not having `constinit` there. Indeed, the early versions of the proposal had constinit as an attribute rather than a keyword, since it didn't really *do* anything. It only gave a compile error for invalid initialization of the variable.

For this case, there is no reason not to make the variable `constexpr`. You clearly don't intend to change the variable, so there's no point in making the variable modifiable.

Answer (score 6):

No, these are not at all the same because `constinit` doesn't make the variable `const`.  As such, the initialization of `Size` isn't even **valid**.  Writing `constinit const` is mostly equivalent to writing `constexpr`, which is semantically **equivalent** to the constant *fold-expression*.  There's no guarantee that any compiler does treat them identically, but in most constant-expression cases there isn't much room for variation.

`constinit` also doesn't imply `inline`: it isn't that the standard "doesn't state whether", it's just that there's nothing to say.  Since there's no point in putting `constinit` and `constexpr` on the same variable, it's not clear what semantics you expect in that area.